# Need help parsing a file via UNIX commands

Tags: unix

I have a file that has lines that look like this

```
LINEID1:FIELD1=ABCD,&FIELD2-0&FIELD3-1&FIELD4-0&FIELD9-0;
LINEID2:FIELD1=ABCD,&FIELD5-1&FIELD6-0;
LINEID3:FIELD1=ABCD,&FIELD7-0&FIELD8-0;

LINEID1:FIELD1=XYZ,&FIELD2-0&FIELD3-1&FIELD9-0
LINEID3:FIELD1=XYZ,&FIELD7-0&FIELD8-0;

LINEID1:FIELD1=PQRS,&FIELD3-1&FIELD4-0&FIELD9-0;
LINEID2:FIELD1=PQRS,&FIELD5-1&FIELD6-0;
LINEID3:FIELD1=PQRS,&FIELD7-0&FIELD8-0;
```

I'm interested in only the lines that begin with LINEID1 and only some elements (FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD4 and FIELD9) from that line. The output should look like this (no & signs.can replace with |)

```
FIELD1=ABCD|FIELD2-0|FIELD4-0|FIELD9-0;
FIELD1=XYZ|FIELD2-0|FIELD9-0;
FIELD1=PQRS|FIELD4-0|FIELD9-0;
```

If additional information is required, do let me know, I'll post them in edits. Thanks!!

Comment: Looks like you want FIELD9, not FIELD5? And XYZ in data doesn't match WXYZ in output.

Comment: Sorry yes you're right. Will correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure awk:

`awk -F ":" ' /LINEID1[^0-9]/{gsub(/FIELD[^1249]+[-=][A-Z0-9]+/,"",$2); gsub(/,*&+/,"|",$2); print $2} ' file`

**Updated to give proper formatting and to omit LINEID11, etc...**

Output:

```
FIELD1=ABCD|FIELD2-0|FIELD4-0|FIELD9-0;
FIELD1=XYZ|FIELD2-0|FIELD9-0
FIELD1=PQRS|FIELD4-0|FIELD9-0;
```

Explanation:

`awk -F ":"` - split lines into LHS ($1) and RHS ($2) since output only requires RHS

`/LINEID1[^0-9]/` - return only lines that match LINEID1 and also ignores LINEID11, LINEID100 etc...

`gsub(/FIELD[^1249]+[-=][A-Z0-9]+/,"",$2)` - remove all fields that aren't 1, 4 or 9 on the RHS

`gsub(/,*&+/,"|",$2)` - clean up the leftover delimiters on the RHS

Comment: This will also find lines with `LINEID10`, `LINEID11` `LINEID199`.

Answer (score 4):

This is not exactly what you asked for, but no-one else is answering and it is pretty close for you to get started with!

```
awk -F'[&:]' '/^LINEID1:/{print $2,$3,$5,$6}' OFS='|' file
```

**Output**

```
FIELD1=ABCD,|FIELD2-0|FIELD4-0|FIELD9-0;
FIELD1=XYZ,|FIELD2-0|FIELD9-0|
FIELD1=PQRS,|FIELD3-1|FIELD9-0;|
```

The `-F` sets the Input Field Separator to colon or ampersand. Then it looks for lines starting `LINEID1:` and prints the fields you need. The `OFS` sets the Output Field Separator to the pipe symbol `|`.

Comment: Thanks! a sed to replace the ','s and the file is good to go !

Comment: You can make the semicolons disappear by telling `awk` they are field separators, so change the `-F'[&:]'` to `-F'[&:;]'`

Comment: Oh! Thanks for that.. my knowledge in UNIX is negligible.. i used sed to get rid of them :D

Answer (score 1):

To select *rows* from data with Unix command lines, use `grep`, `awk`, `perl`, `python`, or `ruby` (in increasing order of power & possible complexity).

To select *columns* from data, use `cut`, `awk`, or one of the previously mentioned scripting languages.

First, let's get only the lines with `LINEID1` (assuming the input is in a file called `input`).

```
grep '^LINEID1' input
```

will output all the lines beginning with `LINEID1`.

Next, extract the columns we care about:

```
grep '^LINEID1' input |   # extract lines with LINEID1 in them
cut -d: -f2           |   # extract column 2 (after ':')
tr ',&' '\n\n'        |   # turn ',' and '&' into newlines
egrep 'FIELD[1249]'   |   # extract only fields FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD4, FIELD9
tr '\n' '|'           |   # turn newlines into '|'
sed -e $'s/\\|\\(FIELD1\\)/\\\n\\1/g' -e 's/\|$//'
```

The last line inserts newlines in front of the `FIELD1` lines, and removes any trailing '|'.

That last `sed` pattern is a little more challenging because `sed` doesn't like literal newlines in its replacement patterns.  To put a literal newline, a `bash` escape needs to be used, which then requires escapes throughout that string.

Here's the output from the above command:

```
FIELD1=ABCD|FIELD2-0|FIELD4-0|FIELD9-0;
FIELD1=XYZ|FIELD2-0|FIELD9-0
FIELD1=PQRS|FIELD4-0|FIELD9-0;
```

This command took only a couple of minutes to cobble up.

Even so, it's bordering on the complexity threshold where I would shift to perl or ruby because of their excellent string processing.

The same script in `ruby` might look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#
while line = gets do
  if line.chomp =~ /^LINEID1:(.*)$/
    f1, others = $1.split(',')
    fields = others.split('&').map {|f| f if f =~ /FIELD[1249]/}.compact
    puts [f1, fields].flatten.join("|")
  end
end
```

Run this script on the same input file and the same output as above will occur:

```
$ ./parse-fields.rb < input
FIELD1=ABCD|FIELD2-0|FIELD4-0|FIELD9-0;
FIELD1=XYZ|FIELD2-0|FIELD9-0
FIELD1=PQRS|FIELD4-0|FIELD9-0;
```